# Label with counter on each bar in matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I have created a simple bar plot to compare two values of a column in a pandas dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Match': {0: 'Match', 1: 'No match', 2: 'Match', 3: 'No match', 4: 'No match'}})
```

Plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()
sns.countplot(df['Match'], color='lightblue')
```

[image]

How can I get a number inside or on top of each bar that represents the number of matches? The *Match* column should have the number 2 and the *No match* column should have the number 3.

I have seen people doing this with huge amounts of additional code, but as a person coming from a BI background, I would assume that matplotlib has some built in functionaility for this, as it can be done quite easily with other tools like PowerBI or Tableau.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try extracting the patches and use `ax.text`:

```
ax = sns.countplot(df['Match'], color='lightblue')
for p in ax.patches:
    ax.text(p.get_x() + p.get_width()/2,
            p.get_height()/2, 
            p.get_height(),
            va='center',
            ha='center'
           )
```

Output:

[image]